# Change colors in scss depending on row data in React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have a grid in a react page and each row is styled with properties from a scss file.  I want to be able to change the color of certain things like row background, border, and a few other things based on a color from the row JSON data.  I don't want to maintain 8 scss files (one for each color).  I want to pass in a color and have it change the values in the scss file.  I'm not sure how to pass the value from React to the scss file.

My main .scss file

```
@import 'variables.scss';

.memberRow{
    width:99%;
    height:55px;
    border:solid 2px $color-member4;
    margin:3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: $color-member4-bg;
}
```

My variables.scss file

```
$color-member1: #65D3E3;
$color-member2: #ED7425;
$color-member3: #F7BC20;
$color-member4: #34B66B;
$color-member5: #9675CC;
$color-member6: #7B8A97;
$color-member7: #2962FF;
$color-member8: #F48FB1;

$color-member1-bg: #65D3E355;
$color-member2-bg: #ED742555;
$color-member3-bg: #F7BC2055;
$color-member4-bg: #34B66B55;
$color-member5-bg: #9675CC55;
$color-member6-bg: #7B8A9755;
$color-member7-bg: #2962FF55;
$color-member8-bg: #F48FB155;
```

Comment: Could you post the JavaScript you're describing?

Comment: I haven't written that portion yet.  I'm trying to get the color changing working first.  I'm basically going to have something like <div className={styles.memberRow}>  in a loop changing the color of each row depending on data.

Comment: I would suggest changing the class via JS or a library like classnames (https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) before trying to dynamically change an SCSS file.

Comment: I have used that before.  What I am trying to avoid is having 8 different versions of a stylesheet that only differ by a few colors.

Comment: The accepted answer by @Andrea - codemillers.com
1012 is what I had in mind. One parent class for the shared styles, and children classes for the colors, toggled on and off with JS as needed. Looks like we have a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would do something like:

```
@import 'variables.scss';

.memberRow{
    width:99%;
    height:55px;
    margin:3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    &.color1 {
       border: solid 2px $color-member1;
       background-color: $color-member1-bg;
    }
    &.color2 {
       ...
    }
}
```

Or extending "base class":

```
.color1 {
   @extend .memberRow;
   border: solid 2px $color-member1;
   background-color: $color-member1-bg;
}
```